# Getting Unique values from xml subset

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to get several unique lists out of one xml file.

The xml format is

```
<Response>
  <Tracks>
        <Track>
              <Name>Track1</Name>
              <Contributors>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>aaa</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>bbb</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>aaa</Name>
                    </Contributor>
              </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
              <Name>Track2</Name>
              <Contributors>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>ddd</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>ReMixer</Role>
                          <Name>bbb</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>ddd</Name>
                    </Contributor>
              </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
              <Name>Track3</Name>
              <Contributors>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>ccc</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>ccc</Name>
                    </Contributor>
                    <Contributor>
                          <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                          <Name>aaa</Name>
                    </Contributor>
              </Contributors>
        </Track>
  </Tracks>
```

So I am required to display the data in the format of track name with the unique recording artists ascosiated with that track

I've looked at keys and preceding sibling things but they dont seem to be explained well enough for me to apply to my problem

Any help appreciated!

-also I am using xslt 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kContributorByListAndName"
             match="Contributor"
             use="concat(generate-id(..),'++',Name)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Contributor
                            [count(.|key('kContributorByListAndName',
                                         concat(generate-id(..),'++',Name))[1])
                             !=1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Response>
    <Tracks>
        <Track>
            <Name>Track1</Name>
            <Contributors>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                    <Name>aaa</Name>
                </Contributor>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                    <Name>bbb</Name>
                </Contributor>
            </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
            <Name>Track2</Name>
            <Contributors>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                    <Name>ddd</Name>
                </Contributor>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>ReMixer</Role>
                    <Name>bbb</Name>
                </Contributor>
            </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
            <Name>Track3</Name>
            <Contributors>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                    <Name>ccc</Name>
                </Contributor>
                <Contributor>
                    <Role>Recording Artist</Role>
                    <Name>aaa</Name>
                </Contributor>
            </Contributors>
        </Track>
    </Tracks>
</Response>
```

Comment: thanks for this, i just found a solution but require explaination to how it works... My data actuall comes back as less than this and to get the contributors I have to do an extension call and pass in an id from the track to get a more complete metadata returned

Comment: so from the a track template i do <xsl:apply-templates select="mfeg:GetTrackMetadata(@ID | ID | ReportingCode | @ReportingCode)/Contributors/Contributor" mode="includesArtists"/>

Comment: <xsl:template match="Contributors/Contributor" mode="includesArtists">            
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('UniqueRecordingArtists', normalize-space(.)))">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()"><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

Comment: with this at the top of the stylesheet

Comment: @Treemonkey: This use a reverse Muenchian Method: instead of selecting "first of a kind", it overwrites an identity rule with an empty rule for "not first of a kind".

Comment: <xsl:key name="UniqueRecordingArtists" match="Response/Tracks/Track/Contributors/Contributor[Role ='Recording Artist']" use="."/>

Comment: @Treemonkey: In your solution you need one more rule because the key is ussing the string value of the element, with no reference to list parent.

Comment: what i've posted above does work but i really have no idea how or why! Its the first time i've used a key or a generate-id(), I would assume that my key is empty?

Comment: @Treemonkey: The key is not empty. It holds the **string value** (the concatenation of all descendant text nodes) of `Contributor` elements with a `Role` child with "Record Artist" string value.

Comment: http://www.mastermixdigital.com/home/mixes/pop.aspx show it in use, where each list following "Includes:" is made up of unique names

Comment: In reply if i do a copy-of my root then the Contributor elements do not exist :?

Comment: i shall make it visiable on the page to which i link you in a moment

Comment: if you inspect the copy of text i did a copy of in the same div as this, where you can see that the Contributor elements are empty or is the Key generated at the time it is called so that i would generate the list from my additional meta-data

Comment: @Treemonkey: Sorry, but I can follow your explanations. Maybe if you post other question with reduce input sample and stylesheet, we will answer these questions better.